# how to build JSON data using ngModel in form and table with ngFor in Angular?

Tags: json, angular, angular2-forms, ngfor

How to build a JSON data using ngModel which is the component is inside form and the table is outside form, which is i have ngModel repeated using ngFor in the table. Here is how my html looked like :

app.component.html :

```
<div>
    <form>
        <div class="form-group row">
            Nama Role : <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="nama_role" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" class="form-control" placeholder="Nama Role" pattern="[a-zA-Z-0-9. ]+">
        </div>
    </form>

    <div>
        Pilih Hak :
        <table class="mytable">
            <tr>
                <th>No</th>
                <th>Kode Aplikasi</th>
                <th>Nama Aplikasi</th>
                <th>View?</th>
                <th>Insert?</th>
                <th>Edit?</th>
                <th>Delete?</th>
            </tr>
            <tr *ngFor="let sources of source; let a=index">
                <td>{{a + 1}}</td>
                <td>{{sources.KODE_APPLICATION}}</td>
                <td>{{sources.NAMA_APPLICATION}}</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="sources.hak_akses" (change)="toggle($event)" /> {{sources.HAK_AKSES}}</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="sources.hak_insert" (change)="toggle($event)" />{{sources.HAK_INSERT}}</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="sources.hak_edit" (change)="toggle($event)" />{{sources.HAK_EDIT}}</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="sources.hak_delete" (change)="toggle($event)" />{{sources.HAK_DELETE}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div class="row show-grid">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="save()">Save</button>
    </div>

</div>
```

and here is my app.component.ts

```
export class frmInputMasterRole {

  public sKodeRole: any;
  sStorage:any;
  hak_akses:any;
  hak_insert:any;
  hak_edit:any;
  hak_delete:any;
  private busyloadevent: IBusyConfig = Object.assign({}, BUSY_CONFIG_DEFAULTS);
  marked = false;

  constructor(private frmInputMasterRoleService: FrmInputMasterRoleService, protected router: Router) {
    this.sKodeRole = 'Auto Generated';
    this.sStorage = sessionStorage.getItem('mAuth');
    this.sStorage = JSON.parse(this.sStorage);

    this.busyloadevent.busy = this.frmInputMasterRoleService.getListRoleDetail().then(
      data => {
        this.source = data;
        console.log(data);
        for (var i of this.source) {
          this.hak_akses = i.HAK_AKSES;
        }
      },
      err => {
           console.log(err);
          }
      }
    );

  }

  save(){
    console.log(this.hak_akses);
  }

  toggle(e){
    console.log(e.target.checked)
  }

  cancel(){
    this.router.navigate(['/pages/master/rolelist']);
  }

}
```

and here is my JSON data when consume my REST API, which is looped with ngFor in source type :

```
[
   {
      "No":"1",
      "KODE_APPLICATION":"APPL00001",
      "NAMA_APPLICATION":"Master Bass",
      "HAK_AKSES":0,
      "HAK_INSERT":0,
      "HAK_EDIT":0,
      "HAK_DELETE":0
   },
   {
      "No":"2",
      "KODE_APPLICATION":"APPL00002",
      "NAMA_APPLICATION":"Master Customer",
      "HAK_AKSES":0,
      "HAK_INSERT":0,
      "HAK_EDIT":0,
      "HAK_DELETE":0
   },
   {
      "No":"3",
      "KODE_APPLICATION":"APPL00003",
      "NAMA_APPLICATION":"Master Teknisi",
      "HAK_AKSES":0,
      "HAK_INSERT":0,
      "HAK_EDIT":0,
      "HAK_DELETE":0
   }
]
```

what i want is i want to build JSON data that looked like this when the last row is checked :

```
{
  "nama_role":test, 
  "details": [{
  "KODE_APPLICATION":"APPL00003",
  "NAMA_APPLICATION":"Master Teknisi",
  "HAK_AKSES":1,
  "HAK_INSERT":0,
  "HAK_EDIT":0,
  "HAK_DELETE":0
   }]
}
```

how do i do this? i dunno where to start since there is a table with ngModel that looped with ngFor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code is attached below:

```
    @Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `<form>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        Nama Role : <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="nama_role" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" class="form-control" placeholder="Nama Role" pattern="[a-zA-Z-0-9. ]+">
                    </div>
               </form>

               <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>No</th>
                        <th>Kode Aplikasi</th>
                        <th>Nama Aplikasi</th>
                        <th>View?</th>
                        <th>Insert?</th>
                        <th>Edit?</th>
                        <th>Delete?</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr *ngFor="let sources of source; let a=index">
                        <td>{{sources.KODE_APPLICATION}}</td>
                        <td>{{sources.NAMA_APPLICATION}}</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox"  [checked]="sources.HAK_AKSES" [(ngModel)]="sources.HAK_AKSES" (change)="toggle(a, sources.HAK_AKSES, \'HAK_AKSES\')"/> {{sources.HAK_AKSES}}</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" [checked]="sources.HAK_INSERT" [(ngModel)]="sources.HAK_INSERT"  (change)="toggle(a, sources.HAK_INSERT, \'HAK_INSERT\')" />{{sources.HAK_INSERT}}</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" [checked]="sources.HAK_EDIT"  [(ngModel)]="sources.HAK_EDIT" (change)="toggle(a, sources.HAK_EDIT, \'HAK_EDIT\')" />{{sources.HAK_EDIT}}</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" [checked]="sources.HAK_DELETE" [(ngModel)]="sources.HAK_DELETE" (change)="toggle(a, sources.HAK_DELETE, \'HAK_DELETE\')" />{{sources.HAK_DELETE}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

                <div class="row show-grid">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="save()">Save</button>
                </div> 
                <custom-comp [myFunc]="handleClick()"></custom-comp>
              `
})

export class MainComponent {

    source = [];

    ngOnInit() {

        this.source = [{
          "No":"1",
          "KODE_APPLICATION":"APPL00001",
          "NAMA_APPLICATION":"Master Bass",
          "HAK_AKSES":1,
          "HAK_INSERT":1,
          "HAK_EDIT":1,
          "HAK_DELETE":0
       },
       {
          "No":"2",
          "KODE_APPLICATION":"APPL00002",
          "NAMA_APPLICATION":"Master Customer",
          "HAK_AKSES":0,
          "HAK_INSERT":0,
          "HAK_EDIT":0,
          "HAK_DELETE":0
       },
       {
          "No":"3",
          "KODE_APPLICATION":"APPL00003",
          "NAMA_APPLICATION":"Master Teknisi",
          "HAK_AKSES":1,
          "HAK_INSERT":0,
          "HAK_EDIT":0,
          "HAK_DELETE":0
       }
    ];
    }

    save() {
        let payload = {
            "nama_role": this.nama_role,
            "details": this.source
        };

        console.log(payload);
    }

    toggle(index, val, key) {
        this.source[index][key] = val ? 1 : 0;
    }
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: can you help me a bit more? in your code there is this line <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="sources.checked" (change)="selectRow(sources, a)" /> i dont want this action, all row must be submited while save, how do i get all? which is changed or not must be exist when save

Comment: and i change this line selectedRows: [] = []; into selectedRows: Array<any> = []; since it show an error

Comment: coolll, it work! but how i give each checkbox default value when repeated? i want to give it false

Comment: Code is updated as per your comment. Only difference is: Initialized your model inside ngOnInit() {} callback and use [checked] attribute to give the default value.

Comment: thank you @suneet Bansal. please one more question, how can i replace the value of true and false from checkbox into 0 or 1?

Comment: Yes. Like this:                                                                                                   {
          "No":"1",
          "KODE_APPLICATION":"APPL00001",
          "NAMA_APPLICATION":"Master Bass",
          "HAK_AKSES":true,
          "HAK_INSERT":false,
          "HAK_EDIT":1,
          "HAK_DELETE":0
       }

Comment: no, i don't want "HAK_AKSES":true, i want it "HAK_AKSES":1 if it's true and 0 if it's false, how do i filter the data before save?

Comment: wow it's works! but i delete the SLASH \'HAK_AKSES\' ups, donee it works it works thanks mannn you just save meeeee